# Problema con isset PHP

Tags: php

tengo un pequeño problemilla y es que yo hago isset de dos variables get las cuales son **Color** y **Talla**, para verificar si existen o no, el problema es que cuando tengo color y talla en la ruta solo muestra como si tuviera la talla o el color, depende de cual se seleccione primero

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET["talla"])) {
        > Código a ejecutar
    } else if(isset($_GET["color"])) {
        > Código a ejecutar
    } else if(isset($_GET["talla"], $_GET["color"])) {
        > Código a ejecutar
    } else {
        > Código a ejecutar
    }
?>
```

¿Podrían ayudarme? gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el problema es de logica:
segun tu script si existe alguna de las dos variables jamas pasara por la tercera

lo correcto seria:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET["talla"], $_GET["color"])) {
        //solo entra si existe los dos indices
        //> Código a ejecutar
    } else {
        if(isset($_GET["talla"])) {
            //solo entra si existe talla
            //> Código a ejecutar
        } 
        if (isset($_GET["color"])) {
            //solo entra si existe color
            //> Código a ejecutar
        }
    }
?>
```

el objetivo de anidar los dos `if` dentro de un `else` es verificar individualmente la existencia de los índices y ejecutar cada …

Comment: Tenías razón, era un fallo en la lógica, tu respuesta me ha funcionado correctamente, muchas gracias amigo